# Tool for distributed task execution

Tags: apache-spark, distributed, distributed-computing

Is it beneficial to use spark just for distributed task execution. I have this requirement of processing huge datasets (read from database, process, write to database) however the processing done is row level. which means I do not have a need for reduce or machine learning.

Would it be an overkill to use spark for this kind of requirement. What would best suit this kind of requirement. I do not want to get into writing software infrastructure which will distribute optimally, handle failures, retries etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is more meant for processing (really) large data sets and In-Memory. One option is to use any open source [IMDG](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/big-data-analytics.html) and process data in a similar fashion but (maybe) with less complexity.

You could also choose your IMDG engine based on what language you want to use it. For .Net you could use [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/whats-new.html#bigdata) and for Java there are many but you could use [TayzGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/big-data-analytics.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From a functionality perspective looks like it would be same for me with either spark or TayzGrid. If data size is the only criteria, my processing  data range from at MBs to hundreds of GBs with different requests.

Comment: Glad to help. Overkill of any technology in use can be calculated by the technical debt it generates. Simply put, is the time and money you put in worth the effort? When you get the answer, you'll choose your technology.